# how to swap the response in the DOM using HTMX when it's 4xx or 5xx response HTTP status codes?

Tags: javascript, html, htmx

I'm trying to do the next using HTMX:

```html
<form hx-boost="true" hx-target="#response" hx-swap="afterbegin">
    <label for="title">Title of your post</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
    <button type="submit">Send post</button>
</form>
<div id="response">
    <!-- Here goes the response from the server -->
</div>
```

In the server, the internal logic is:

When the title of the post is empty returns some `div` with a message that indicates an error in the request and also responds with a 400 HTTP status code, but when I do all of that, the response isn't beign swapped (of course if the HTTP status is 200, anything that comes from the server is swapped in).

I tried something curious and it's, if you disable javascript in the browser, the page is full reloaded and loads the div correctly.

It's not a Content-Type header error because the CT header is `text/html; charset=utf-8` when the server responds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. HTMX need additional script to work with error response, you can add this `<script src='https://unpkg.com/htmx.org/dist/ext/response-targets.js'></script>`, along with your HTMX script.
2. You must wrap with outer element using attributte hx-ext="response-targets".
3. Use `hx-target-4xx` or `hx-target-5xx` attributes to work with error response.

Your code should be working if it's like this:

```html
<div hx-ext='response-targets'>
  <form hx-boost="true" hx-target="#response" hx-target-4xx='#errorResponse' hx-swap="afterbegin">
      <label for="title">Title of your post</label>
      <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
      <button type="submit">Send post</button>
  </form>
  <div id="response">
      <!-- Here goes the response from the server -->
  </div>
  <div id="errorResponse">
      <!-- Here goes the error response from the server -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I use `hx-ext="response-targets"` in the body tag so the scope is global?

Comment: I'm new in htmx btw. i think you can, but idk if it will confilct with another request or not. Maybe someone who had more experience working with htmx can explain it.